# The program 'tclsh' is currently not installed?

Tags: tcl, ubuntu-16.04, tk-toolkit

I am trying to install the tcl/tk8.4 version on my ubuntu16.04 machine. After completing the apt-get install command. if i type tclsh command. I am getting this error message saying:The program 'tclsh' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing. sudo atp-get install tcl.

```
 The steps followed are as follows: 
 1. I have removed the latest tcl/tk8.6, using autoremove commands 
 2.dccom@dccom-vm:~$ sudo apt-get install tk8.4 tcl8.4
 [sudo] password for dccom:
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree
 Reading state information... Done
 The following additional packages will be installed:
 libtk8.4
 Suggested packages:
 tcl-tclreadline
 The following NEW packages will be installed:
   libtk8.4 tcl8.4 tk8.4
 0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 350 not upgraded.
 Need to get 567 kB/581 kB of archives.
 After this operation, 1.858 kB of additional disk space will be used.
 Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
 Get:1 http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 libtk8.4 
 i386 8.4.20-8 [556 kB]
 Get:2 http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 tk8.4 i386 
 8.4.20-8 [11,5 kB]
 Fetched 567 kB in 1s (331 kB/s)
 Selecting previously unselected package libtk8.4:i386.
 (Reading database ... 276714 files and directories currently installed.)
 Preparing to unpack .../libtk8.4_8.4.20-8_i386.deb ...
 Unpacking libtk8.4:i386 (8.4.20-8) ...
 Selecting previously unselected package tcl8.4.
 Preparing to unpack .../tcl8.4_8.4.20-8_i386.deb ...
 Unpacking tcl8.4 (8.4.20-8) ...
 Selecting previously unselected package tk8.4.
 Preparing to unpack .../tk8.4_8.4.20-8_i386.deb ...
 Unpacking tk8.4 (8.4.20-8) ...
 Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu4) ...
 Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
 Setting up libtk8.4:i386 (8.4.20-8) ...
 Setting up tcl8.4 (8.4.20-8) ...
 Setting up tk8.4 (8.4.20-8) ...
 Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu4) ...

 Error info:

 dccom@dccom-vm:~$ tclsh
 The program 'tclsh' is currently not installed. You can install it by 
 typing:
 sudo apt install tcl
```

Do I need to set any environment variables here ? Please suggest.

Comment: Any reason why you want to downgrade to 8.4? Tcl, unlike other languages, is very forwards compatible. You can run a tcl 7.0 program on 8.6 with no issues. Anyway, recent versions of bash cache paths to executables. Usually you just need to close your terminal and open another terminal to fix this.

Comment: @slebetman : Yes, I have to install spirent test center linux env, Which supports lower version of tcl 8.4 to 8.5.14.  Its mentioned in STC specifications.

Answer (score 2):

The `tclsh` program will be installed with the name `tclsh8.4` by default; use `which tclsh8.4` to find where it actually is. This makes it much easier to have multiple versions of Tcl in use on one system. However, if you want to make it default, you should use [`update-alternatives`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/update-alternatives.8.html). Try typing this (at a root prompt or via `sudo`):

```
update-alternatives --config tclsh
```

You might also need a similar thing for `wish` (which is installed as `wish8.4` by default).

Comment: Thanks,  I found the issue . For tcl 4.8 we need to create some soft link in /usr/bin/ to tclsh.  I missed it .. its working fine now ..